# Is it possible to binds to resize event when dragging on grid in jQuery.draggable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I use [jQuery.draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) plugin with the following config:

```
   this.$el.draggable({
        scroll: false,
        axis: false,
        opacity: 0.5,
        helper: 'clone',
        grid: [100, 100]
        drag: function (e, ui) {
          console.log('Dragging');
        }
    });
```

At now drag event fires on every mouse move but I need to trigger this event only when I drag my element on grid (option: grid: [100, 100]).

How could I bind on that event?

**EDIT:** example http://jsfiddle.net/FNhFX/5/

Comment: what is your this variable? are you sure it's what you expect? can you post the fiddle?

Comment: I need to execute some code in factual dragging instead mousemove. Here is exanple http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: I've just added example on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "containment" option:
http://jsfiddle.net/FNhFX/38/

I have updated your fiddle with that option

```
$(function() {
    $(".drag-item").draggable({
        grid: [20, 20],
        containment: "parent"
    });
    $(".outside-drag-item").draggable({
        grid: [20, 20],
        helper:"clone"
    });
    $(".drop-target").droppable({
        accept: ".drag-item"
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately triggers 'drag' event on every mouse move. So even if I don't drag element I'll have 20 console.log('drag')  nonetheless

Comment: drag event is fired only when you have the right button of the mouse pressed. Not in your case?